# Is there a fix for 404 not found with flask?

Tags: python, flask

## When I run this code it gives a "404 page not found" error

```
from flask import Flask, render_template 

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/Home')
def home():
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: More information: Yes I am using http://127.0.0.1:5000/Home

Comment: It works for me - I copied your code and ran it, then visited the URL you added in a comment, and it worked. What output do you see on your terminal when you run this code?

Comment: What does your console output when you start the server? Could it be listening on a different ip/port?

Comment: * Serving Flask app "index" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Jul/2020 17:08:52] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Jul/2020 17:08:58] "GET /Home HTTP/1.1" 404 -

Comment: It could be because I Am using sublime text because I just re-installed pycharm and it works fine there

Comment: @Caleb check if .. have you written `@app.route('/Home')` or `@app.route('/Home/')` in your flask app ?

Answer (score 0):

You should set the route to home as just "/"

```
@app.route('/')
def home():
  ...
```

or visit `/Home` in your browser

Comment: Yes. I have tried both. Could it have something to do with the installation of flask. I am using ubuntu. Everything runs fine but the actual page returns a 404

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the last line to `app.run(host='0.0.0.0')` and then use localhost:5000 to access the API. Here is a great tutorial I've used on setting up Flask on Ubuntu: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uswgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04.